# Xcode 6 UITableView makes view black

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am working on my first iOS app in Swift and I have an issue where one of my Tab Bar views turns black in the iOS Simulator (iPhone 6) when I add constraints to my elements. I figured out I can *somtimes* "fix" the issue by removing all of the constraints and adding them back in, but whenever I change anything I have to do it again, and it's really annoying.

Is this a bug, or is there some subtle way of fixing this issue permanently?

**Edit:** I just found out the issue is with my Label. If I set its width or height constraints, it makes the whole screen black. Not sure why. On my first Tab View, I have the same label and it works fine. Also it looks different, despite having the same font and position. Seems like something quirky with the Storyboard editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It was because I was linking a reference outlet of a Table View to the View Controller, according to some tutorial. This is bad and it messed up everything. The View Controller can serve as a delegate for the Table View, but it needs an explicit variable reference to call methods on the Table View itself.

Comment: So... can you describe the right way to do it? I think I fell for the same tutorial...